# build website for mobile and pc with django

Tags: django, templates, mobile

I am trying to develop a website for mobile and pc browser with django.
and I am trying to figure out a best structure of the views and templates. 
there is what I have tried:

1) use different url ( like http://example.com/mobile/ and http://example.com/ OR
  http://example.com/?c=mobile ) to distinguish mobile and pc, and map them to different view which set different templates.

2) in the view set different template according to USER_CLIENT

3) use a wrapper layer of the view, the actual view just return the data to the wrapper, the wrapper set the different template.

Is there a common way to handle this in django?  any suggestions and comments?

Comment: As user I expect to find mobile pages under `m.example.org` or `mobile.example.org`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Django's ["sites" framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) for a  mobile version at `http://m.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommended solution 3; using a decorator to inspect the clients User Agent and returning à different template in case of a mobile agent.

Have the decorator take two arguments: the normal template, and the mobile template.

From your view, return a dict The decorator may pass to the rendering function as context. There is a decorator called 'render_to' that does this very well, Google for it.

To deal with the use case where users want the full version, even when browsing from a mobile device, you may use a redirecting view that sets a cookie your decorator may check for.

Answer (score 0):

best practice: use [minidetector](http://code.google.com/p/minidetector/) to add the extra info to the request, then use django's built in request context to pass it to your templates like so.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def my_view_on_mobile_and_desktop(request)
    .....
    render_to_response('regular_template.html', 
                       {'my vars to template':vars}, 
                       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

then in your template you are able to introduce stuff like:

```
<html>
  <head>
  {% block head %}
    <title>blah</title>
  {% if request.mobile %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/styles/base-mobile.css">
  {% else %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/styles/base-desktop.css">
  {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navigation">
      {% include "_navigation.html" %}
    </div>
    {% if not request.mobile %}
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p> sidebar content not fit for mobile </p>
    </div>
    {% endif %>
    <div id="content">
      <article>
        {% if not request.mobile %}
        <aside>
          <p> aside content </p>
        </aside>
        {% endif %}
        <p> article content </p>
      </aricle>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```